# An unusual identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $$\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6}+\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6}}{6}\right)^m=\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}+\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}}{2}\right)^n$$ for all natural integers $m,n$.

Comment: That could only be the case if both bracketed expressions equal one; do they?

Comment: Yes it is so the problem is to prove the numerators are $6$ and $2$ respectively. I expected an answer given by beginners.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hint: for the LHS let $\,a=\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6}\,, \,b=\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6}\,$ then $\,a^3+b^3=162\,$ and $\,ab=3\,$, so: $$\,(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=162+9(a+b)\,$$

But the equation $x^3-9x-162=0$ has only one real root which is $x=6$, therefore $a+b=6$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] As pointed out by @LordSharktheUnknown, the RHS would need to be $5^{th}$ roots in order for the equality to hold, rather than *cube* roots as posted.

An argument like the above works in that case, too. Let $a=\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}\,$, $b=\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}$ then $a^5+b^5=82$ and $ab=-1\,$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
(a+b)^5 &= a^5+b^5+5ab(a^3+b^3)+10a^2b^2(a+b) \\
 &= a^5+b^5 +5ab\big((a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)\big)+10a^2b^2(a+b) \\
 &= 82 - 5\big((a+b)^3+3(a+b)\big)+10(a+b) \\
 &= 82 - 5(a+b)^3 - 5(a+b)
\end{align}
$$

But the equation $x^5+5x^3+5x-82=0$ has only one real root $x=2$, therefore $a+b=2$.

Answer (score 11):

Hint: if the left side doesn't depend on $m$, the quantity inside parentheses must be either $0$ or $1$.  Similarly for the right side.

Further hint: $\sqrt[3]{81 \pm 33 \sqrt{6}}$ have the form $a \pm b \sqrt{6}$ for suitable integers $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4):

The problem statement is erroneous. The second bracket should be
$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}+\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}}2.$$
Note that $41+29\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt2)^5$, so $\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt2$.
Similarly $\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}=1-\sqrt2$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}+\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}}2=1.$$

Comment: Nice catch (+1). I edited my answer to that effect, don't think it overlaps with your radical denesting cue.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(
   \frac{\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6}+\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6}}{6}
\right)^m
=\left(
   \frac{\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}+\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2}}{2}
\right)^n$$

For this to be true, we must have
$$\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6}+\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6} = 6$$ and
$$\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2}+\sqrt[5]{41-29\sqrt2} = 2$$

if $\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6}+\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6}$ is going to be $6$, then, for some $n$

$\sqrt[3]{81+33\sqrt6} = 3+n\sqrt 6$ and $\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6} = 3-n\sqrt 6$
for some $n$. So

\begin{align}
   81 + 33\sqrt6 &= 27 + 27 \sqrt 6 n + 54 n^2 + 6 \sqrt 6 n^3 \\
   81 - 33\sqrt6 &= 27 - 27 \sqrt 6 n + 54 n^2 - 6 \sqrt 6 n^3 \\
\hline
   162 &=54 + 108 n^2 \\
   n &= 1
\end{align}

We find that $(3 + \sqrt 6)^3 = 81 + 33\sqrt6$
and $(3 - \sqrt 6)^3 = 81 - 33\sqrt6$.

Similarly, if $\sqrt[5]{81+33\sqrt6}+\sqrt[3]{81-33\sqrt6}$ has to be equal to $2$, then $\sqrt[5]{41+29\sqrt2} = 1 + n\sqrt 2$
and $\sqrt[3]{41-29\sqrt2} = 1 - n\sqrt 2$. So

\begin{align}
   41+29\sqrt2 
   &= 1 + 5 \sqrt 2 n + 20 n^2 + 20 \sqrt 2 n^3 + 20 n^4 + 4 \sqrt 2 n^5 \\
   41-29\sqrt2 
   &= 1 - 5 \sqrt 2 n + 20 n^2 - 20 \sqrt 2 n^3 + 20 n^4 - 4 \sqrt 2 n^5 \\
\hline
   82 &= 2 + 40 n^2 + 40n^4 \\
   n &= 1
\end{align}

We find that $(1 + \sqrt 2)^5 = 41+29\sqrt2$
and $(1 - \sqrt 2)^5 = 41-29\sqrt2$.